# Detecting empty querystring with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a strange problem, where to generate pages I am using my URL's as:

site/city/city-name/page-number

for that mod_rewrite is:

```
RewriteRule ^city/(.*)/(.*)$ tagcity.php?tag=$1&pnum=$2 [L]
```

But now the problem is if I delete the city-name and make it empty like "site/city//page-number" then it starts taking page-number as city-name.

Also can I have only one rewrite to serve pages with or without page numbers?

I know its a strange situation but unfortunatly some of my sites pages are indexed in Google as above.

How to detect that its empty so I can generate a 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `+` instead:

```
RewriteRule ^city/(.+)/(.*)$ tagcity.php?tag=$1&pnum=$2 [L,QSA]
```

---

`*` means "0 or more repetitions", whereas `+` means "1 or more repetitions". Thus using a `+` requires that field to have at least *something* in it.

---

Also, you may want to make that `[L,QSA]` so that if there are any additional query parameters in the original URL, they'll be preserved. (QSA = Query String Append)

---

As requested in the comments, a rule with the ability to handle completely missing page number:

```
RewriteRule ^city/([^/]+)(?:/(.*))?$ tagcity.php?tag=$1&pnum=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Its working but currently I have 2 rewites:

    RewriteRule ^city/(.+)/(.*)$ tagcity.php?tag=$1&pnum=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^city/(.*)$ tagcity.php?tag=$1 [L]

Can I have only one to handle both type of requests with or without page numbers?

Comment: I think I've added something that will work for you, though I haven't tested it. If the page number is missing, it'll just pass `pnum=` (empty string).

Comment: Its working but again original problem of empty city string is back. Means if I delete the city name it takes page number as city name.

"city/delhi/1" make this to "city//1" then 1 becomes city name.

Comment: Hm. It shouldn't, considering that `city/([^/]+)` won't match `city//1`.

Comment: If your city names don't contain numbers, you could change `[^/]` to `[^/0-9]`.

Comment: new question is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052830/how-to-rewrite-these-urls-for-country-state-city